# Execute sp_executesql, Table Variabe not Declared

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am Using SQL server 2012 and i want to select random columns from my table by applying `where` condition in this query:

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql
          N'SELECT * 
            FROM @table
            WHERE @Col = @Value',
            N'@Value nvarchar(44),@table nvarchar(55),@Col nvarchar(30)',
            @Value = 'Cus_1',@Col='CustId',@table='SaleOrder';
```

But when I execute it, it shows error

> Must declare the table variable "@table"

I also tried it to declare by this: `@table table(Id nvarchar(30))`, but thin it shows again an error on table type...

Please help

Comment: Yes Mat, i am using SQL server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are trying to run:

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql
      N'SELECT * FROM @table WHERE @Col = @Value',
      N'@Value nvarchar(44), @table nvarchar(55), @Col nvarchar(30)',
      @Value = 'Cus_1', @Col='CustId', @table='SaleOrder';
```

Alas.  You cannot substitute in a table name or column name using parameter substitution.  So, SQL Server is looking for a table variable called `@table`.  You can fix this by putting the values directly into the string:

```
declare @Col = 'CustId', @table = 'SaleOrder';
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT * FROM ' + @table + ' WHERE ' + @Col + ' = @Value';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql,
      N'@Value nvarchar(44)',
      @Value = 'Cus_1';
```

Unfortunately, I cannot find a good reference in the documentation that explains what is happening.  When a statement is compiled, it is allowed to have parameters.  However, the parameters are for *values* in the statement, not for column, table, database, or UDF names or for keywords.  The statement itself is compiled, with place holders for the parameters, and in order to be compiled, the SQL engine needs to resolve all object names.

Comment: Thnx Very Much Gordon, Its Working :)